# Overload de funciones en struct

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy intentando hacer una pequeña librería de Menu para Arduino, y en ella intento poner un callback a una función configurable a través de un Struct.

```
typedef struct _MENU_ITEM
{
  byte Type;
  const char *Text;
  void (*Function)();
  _MENU_ITEM *SubItems;
} MENU_ITEM;
```

Funciona correctamente, pero es algo limitado en que no le puedo poner una función con argumentos o con un tipo de retorno que no sea void. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de crear un overload de la función, que permita usar el mismo dato para añadir una función con argumentos y/o un tipo de retorno distinto de void, o si por el contrario tengo que crear distintos structs para ello. Algo así:

```
typedef struct _MENU_ITEM
{
  byte Type;
  const char *Text;
  void (*Function)();
  bool (*Function)(bool status);
  _MENU_ITEM *SubItems;
} MENU_ITEM;
```

He estado buscando y no he visto nada (o no lo he entendido bien), y es más que nada por las limitaciones de memoria que tiene Arduino, que si tengo que crear varios structs y generar funciones para todos ellos, el programa se vuelve más grande y pesado.

¡Un saludo! y ¡gracias!

Comment: El IDE de Arduino usa C++, no C. En C++ tienes plantillas. En ambos casos, puedes usar [*uniones*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union) y [*funciones variádicas*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic).

Comment: @Trauma, luego le echo un vistazo más a fondo y hago pruebas, pero tiene pinta de que es lo que necesito. Gracias por apuntarme en la buena dirección. Es la primera vez que hago algo más grande en C++, utilizo structs y mi primera clase, así que hay muchas cosas que se me escapan todavía ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de crear un overload de la función, que permita usar el mismo dato para añadir una función con argumentos y/o un tipo de retorno distinto de void

No, no puedes sobrecargar la función salvo que el número de posibilidades esté acotado. ¿Por qué? Básicamente porque cada tipo de función necesitará un puntero a función diferente... los punteros a función no son clases y no admiten herencia ni sobrecarga, luego al final tendrías que tener una colección de punteros a funciones ... no suena muy práctico.

Si en el diseño de un menú, que se supone que es algo abstracto, tienes que poner características no abstractas (como son punteros a funcion particularizados), entonces tu arquitectura tiene un problema de diseño.

Por ponerte varios ejemplos:

- Las funciones que hacen las veces de ciclo de eventos de las aplicaciones windows tienen **todas** la misma interfaz ... y lo mismo pasa para los diferentes escritorios de Linux.
- Los callback de los eventos en windows (los que hablan con la API de Windows) tienen **todos** la misma interfaz

Esto se hace así por varios motivos:

- Sencillez: Un código sencillo es más facil de mantener
- La complejidad corre a cargo del cliente. El cliente conoce exactamente sus necesidades, la librería no. Es responsabilidad del cliente implementar todas las complejidades que crea conveniente ... la librería debe ser facil de usar
- Aislamiento: La librería debería preocuparse únicamente de funciones propias. En este caso de generar y mostrar el menú. Todas las características que no sean propias del menú corren a cargo del cliente de la librería.
- Dependencias La librería debería proporcionar un uso genérico y no particular. En caso contrario su reusabilidad está en entredicho ya que antes o después acabará adquiriendo dependencias innecesarias
- ...

Así pues, una cosa es que tu implementes una función que, por ejemplo, indique qué opción del menú ha lanzado el evento:

```
struct MenuItem
//     ^ Los identificadores que empiezan por _ están reservados por el lenguaje
{
  void (*Function)(MenuItem*);
};
```

O bien puedes optar por una función ligeramente diferente que se adapte a tus necesidades ... pero no tiene sentido implementar un catálogo de funciones si no hay una causa que lo justifique seriamente.

Piensa, poniendo como caso tu respuesta:

```
void (*Function1)();
bool (*Function2)(bool status);
```

Cómo quedaría la lógica de tu menú ... debería ser tu librería quien invocase el *callback*, así que:

- ¿Tiene que comprobar a qué función llamar en cada llamada?
- ¿Realmente es necesaria esa sobrecarga?
- Y si ya has puesto dos funciones ... ¿Quién te impide añadir 2 más? ¿o 20 más? ¿400 quizá? ¿Por qué unas sí y otras no? ¿quién va a mantener entonces la lógica del *callback*?

Por otro lado, fíjate que la segunda opción puede reemplazar perfectamente a la primera. Simplemente basta con ignorar el parámetro de entrada y devolver un valor por defecto:

```
bool miCallback(bool)
//              ^^^^ ignoro el parámetro de entrada
{
  // ...

  return true; // o false ... retorno genérico
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Entiendo lo que dices y es un buen punto de vista, y quizá lo implemente así. En principio lo quería hacer así por simplificar su uso, ya que para un cliente no es lo mismo decirle a la librería que ejecute una función concreta al pulsar una opción, que tener que andar buscando qué opción se ha pulsado. Sobre la marcha estoy pensando en añadirle un ID a cada entrada del menú y usarlo para el filtrado.

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín no necesitas mirar qué opción se ha elegido, basta con asignar a cada opción del menú un callback distinto. Así, la opción, "leer archivo", por ejemplo, solo se preocupa de leer un archivo.  Por otro lado, lo del id es una opción ampliamente utilizada

Answer (score 1):

He estado haciendo pruebas con union y me quedó así:

```
typedef struct _MENU_ITEM
{
  byte Type;
  const char *Text;
  union Function {
    void (*Function1)();
    bool (*Function2)(bool status);

    bool operator !=(const int compare) const{
      return Function1 != compare &&
      Function2 != compare;
    }
    bool operator ==(const int compare) const{
      return Function1 == compare &&
      Function2 == compare;
    }
  } Function;
  _MENU_ITEM *SubItems;
} MENU_ITEM;
```

Tuve que añadir dos operadores porque necesitaba verificar si son NULL, pero parece funcionar correctamente.
De todas formas lo de las templates con funciones variádiacas puede ser interesante también, por lo que posiblemente lo intente hacer aunque sea para aprenderlo.

Un saludo, y gracias @Trauma por tu ayuda.